# Hiding based on previous combo box choice in xpages?

Tags: xpages

I have 3 comboboxes

Combo1
Combo2
Combo3

If Combo1 is blank (no selection) then combo2 is hidden.  If Combo2 is blank then Combo3 is hidden.

If Combo1 is changed, it blanks Combo2, if Combo2 is changed it blanks Combo3.

This is because Combo2 choices are determined by Combo1 and Combo3 choices by Combo2.  This is all working well.

What is happening if I change Combo1 then Combo2 and Combo3 are being blanked just as expected  but Combo3 is not being hidden.   If all I do is change Combo1 again, Combo3 is hidden.   It is almost like I need 2 update events.

Is there any way around this?

Update

The issue seems to be with comboboxes that have computed selection values.  In the sample below, changing the State should cause the ShowRoom scope variable to be "0"   Changing Floor sets it to "1". A Computed Field will show the current value of the scope variable. It appears the onChange event of the State combo box is not being triggered.  If you change the city selection from computed to static values then it works fine.

```
    Not&#160;Working (Computed&#160;Selections)<xp:table style="width:100%" id="tblSurvey2">

    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td style="width:300px">
            <xp:label value="*State" style="width:66.0px" styleClass="FieldLabel" id="label1">
            </xp:label>

        </xp:td>
        <xp:td style="width:745.0px">

            <xp:comboBox id="comboBoxState2" style="width:173.0px">



                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tblSurvey2">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("ShowRoom2","0");}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>






                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="AL"></xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="CA"></xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="NY"></xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="PA"></xp:selectItem>
            </xp:comboBox>
            State =&#160;
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("comboBoxState2").getValue()}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
            &#160;&#160;&#160;Show Room =&#160;
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField4">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.get("ShowRoom2");}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr id="tr1">

        <xp:td style="width:300px">
            <xp:label value="*City" style="width:66.0px" styleClass="FieldLabel" id="label2">
            </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td style="width:785.0px">
            <xp:comboBox id="comboBoxCity2" style="width:175.0px">

                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="norefresh" id="eventHandler1">
                </xp:eventHandler>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tblSurvey2" id="eventHandler2"></xp:eventHandler>










                <xp:selectItems>
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:new Array(getComponent("comboBoxState2").getValue() + " City1", getComponent("comboBoxState2").getValue() + " City2", getComponent("comboBoxState2").getValue() + " City3");}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:selectItems>
            </xp:comboBox>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>

    <xp:tr id="tr2">

        <xp:td style="width:300px">
            <xp:label value="*Floor" style="width:66.0px" styleClass="FieldLabel" id="label3">
            </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td style="width:745.0px">
            <xp:comboBox id="comboBoxFloor2" style="width:89.0px">

                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="norefresh" id="eventHandler5">
                </xp:eventHandler>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tblSurvey2" id="eventHandler7">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("ShowRoom2","1");}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>




                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Floor1"></xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Floor2"></xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Floor3"></xp:selectItem>
            </xp:comboBox>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr id="tr3">
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.get("ShowRoom2") == "1";}]]></xp:this.rendered>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="*Room" style="width:66.0px" styleClass="FieldLabel" id="label6">
            </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:comboBox id="comboBoxRoom2" style="width:89.0px">                   
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="A"></xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="B"></xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="C"></xp:selectItem>
            </xp:comboBox>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
  </xp:table>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are using partial refresh to do this?
So you have

```
C1 -> C2/C3
C2 -> C3
```

Since you only can have one partial refresh target you need to wrap C2/C3 into a panel and target that one for C1's partial refresh. Also check how you hide C3. you might want to use a viewScope variable to manage the states and depend your visibility on that one.

Update: You should **bind** your fields to viewScope variables, not set extra values. Also: a combobox shows when the bound variable value is missing or has no match the first value, but doesn't reflect it. So in a combobox you always need to have a first value that makes sense "-Please select|-" is common or looking up the actual first value. In your case the "please select" makes sense. You also might consider if you really want to hide the fields (that becomes a "mystery meat" navigation) or just update the possible selections (remove the rendered properties from the example below to see how it works).

Here you go:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:table style="width:100%" id="tblSurvey2">
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td style="width:300px">
            <xp:label value="*State" style="width:66.0px"
                styleClass="FieldLabel" id="label1">
            </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td style="width:745.0px">
            <xp:comboBox id="comboBoxState2" style="width:173.0px"
                value="#{viewScope.selectedState}">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tblSurvey2" id="eventHandler2">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.selectedCity = "-";
viewScope.selectedFloor = "-";
       viewScope.selectedRoom = "-";}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="-Please select-"
                    itemValue="-" id="selectItem1">
                </xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="AL" itemValue="AL" id="selectItem2"></xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="CA" itemValue="CA" id="selectItem3"></xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="NY" itemValue="NY" id="selectItem4"></xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="PA" itemValue="PA" id="selectItem5"></xp:selectItem>
            </xp:comboBox>

        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr id="tr1" style="background-color:rgb(253,250,227)">
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.selectedState && (viewScope.selectedState != "-")}]]></xp:this.rendered>
        <xp:td style="width:300px">
            <xp:label value="*City" styleClass="FieldLabel"
                id="label2">
            </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td style="width:785.0px">
            <xp:comboBox id="comboBoxCity2"
                value="#{viewScope.selectedCity}">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" id="eventHandler1" refreshId="tblSurvey2">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.selectedFloor = "-";
  viewScope.selectedRoom = "-";}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
                <xp:selectItems id="selectItems1">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var hasState = viewScope.selectedState && (viewScope.selectedState != "-");
 var result = ["-Please select-|-"];
 var cities = viewScope.selectedState + " " + ["City1","City2","City3"];
 for (var x in cities) {
result.push(cities[x]);
 };
 return hasState ? result : "Please select a state first|-"; 
 }]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:selectItems>
            </xp:comboBox>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>

    <xp:tr id="tr2">

        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.selectedCity && (viewScope.selectedCity != "-")}]]></xp:this.rendered>
        <xp:td style="width:300px">
            <xp:label value="*Floor" style="width:66.0px"
                styleClass="FieldLabel" id="label3">
            </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td style="width:745.0px">
            <xp:comboBox id="comboBoxFloor2"
                value="#{viewScope.selectedFloor}">

                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" id="eventHandler5" refreshId="tblSurvey2">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.selectedRoom = "-";}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
                <xp:selectItems id="selectItems2">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var hasCity = viewScope.selectedCity && (viewScope.selectedCity != "-");
  var result = ["-Please select-|-"];
  var floors = viewScope.selectedCity + " " + ["Floor1","Floor2","Floor3"];
  for (var x in floors) {
result.push(floors[x]);
  };
  return hasCity ? result : "Please select a city first|-"; 
  }]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:selectItems>
            </xp:comboBox>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr id="tr3" style="background-color:rgb(253,250,227)">

        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.selectedFloor && (viewScope.selectedFloor != "-")}]]></xp:this.rendered>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="*Room" style="width:66.0px"
                styleClass="FieldLabel" id="label6">
            </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:comboBox id="comboBoxRoom2"
                value="#{viewScope.selectedRoom}">
                <xp:selectItems id="selectItems3">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var hasFloor = viewScope.selectedFloor && (viewScope.selectedFloor != "-");
    var result = ["-Please select-|-"];
    var rooms = viewScope.selectedFloor + " " + ["Room A","Room B","Room C"];
    for (var x in rooms) {
    result.push(rooms[x]);
  };
   return hasFloor ? result : "Please select a floor first|-"; }]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:selectItems>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField4" id="eventHandler3">
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:comboBox>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>Current variables</xp:td>
        <xp:td>State:
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{viewScope.selectedState}">
</xp:text>
<xp:br></xp:br>
City:
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2" value="#{viewScope.selectedCity}">
</xp:text>
<xp:br></xp:br>
Floor:
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3" value="#{viewScope.selectedFloor}">

</xp:text>
<xp:br></xp:br>Room:
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField4" value="#{viewScope.selectedRoom}">
    </xp:text></xp:td></xp:tr></xp:table></xp:view>
```

You could simplify the code by moving the "please select" into its own value item and use a function rather repeating code, but you get the idea.

Comment: The combo boxes are already in a table.  Each updates the whole table.   Sorry should have mentioned that.

Comment: Did you try binding the fields to viewScope variables and use those in the hide formulas?

Comment: This appears to be a refresh issue similar to order of refresh in a regular notes form.   Besides implementing scope variables to viewscope variables seems far more complicated then it is worth for this issue.

Comment: The issues seems to be with when a combo box has it's selections computed.   All works fine when all the combo boxes have static values.  If even one combobox  has a computed value then it seems to mess up the on change event of the combobox.  I am going to try and update my post above with an example.

Comment: It is about what happens when you don't have the value the box is providing. Sample above works

Comment: Thanks.  I think I finally understand the issue.  I used your idea modified it to use the bound document fields instead of the scope variables as you used in the example.   Works great.  Though I did learn a thing or two about binding scope variables and how the value can be obtained from your sample.

Comment: Glad it helped. I actually prefer using the scope (or a bean in the scope) since it gives a better abstraction. If you change your control type then you don't need to alter other places as long as a new control binds to the same scope variable

Comment: You showed an easy way to bind the scope variable to the control.   Is there just as easy of a way to bind the scope variable to the document?  So if control changes scope variable, variable changes document field.   I know it can be down in query save but thought there might be a better way.

Comment: I actually use a scope bean to do most of the stuff and the bean would have a save method which then writes it where it needs to be written. Another abstraction - might be a document for now, but could be anything else

Answer (score 1):

you can execute multiple partial updates with some javascript. Take a look at this:

http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_events_and_partial_or_full_refresh

Comment: This is a client side example.   Any way to do it with SSJS?

Comment: Plus I am getting an error. Just for testing, I added a button and a table to a xpage.  The CSJS click event of the button has XSP.partialRefreshGet("#id:{tblSurvey}");   but I get a javascript error: I have no formId or reference to it on my page.


Message: 'formId' is null or not an object
Line: 16
Char: 15985
Code: 0

Comment: I was running into the 8.5.3 bug with partial refresh  Here is a fix:
http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2012/03/patch-for-bug-in-xsppartialrefreshget.html  But now I am getting No element to submit with id #id:{tblSurvey}.  I have a table on the xPage with an id of tblSurvey.   If I enter the full client id then it works.

Comment: you said above your using: #id:{tblSurvey} , this should be #{id:tblSurvey}, is this you issue ?

Comment: Yeah found that thanks.   But I still have an issue with the view formulas not working the way I want.