# Delete value(s) in the list box by click a button

Tags: xpages

[22 Feb 2016 update]

Regarding my previous questions about list box, I can move values between two listboxes and save values after I receive useful answers.

However, if I retrieve those saved values, the listboxes can display the proper values but I cannot move those values and get exception message.

I can only move values between two listboxes if I don't save them.

Therefore, I am planning to have another button for delete listboxes values. I am not sure this is a good practice/design in xpages but I don't have a better method solve the exception.

I am sorry if I caused any inconvenience in this question. Thank you.

[23 Feb 2016 update]

According to the latest comments and answer, I notice that I made a big mistake because I mixed the document and value together.

I decide to break the design into few steps to find the problem occurs.

Due to I can move values between two listboxes and save them. I use another listbox test whether I can retrieve those saved values or not.

The third list box, I use View Scope Variable(similar to listbox B) but I use another variable name to avoid vague.

Here is my code of the third listbox:

```
var item = getComponent("comboBox4").getValue();

if ((item == null) || (null == item))
{ 
    return "void";
}
else if ((item != null) || (null != item))
{ 
    var lookupItem = @DbLookup(@DbName(),"ViewName", item,3  )
    return  lookupItem;
}
if (!viewScope.totalItems) 
{
    viewScope.totalItems = [lookupItem];
 }
 return viewScope.totalItems;
```

In the combo box, I use onchange partial update and apply to the third list box . When I run the program, I select a value from the combo box, the third listbox  can display the relevant values that I saved before.

That part is fine, so I keep the third listbox for testing. And I put some dummy but unique data (to prevent confusion) related to the combo box.

Here is my first attempt: I choose a value from a combo box, the third listbox  can display the relevant values that I saved. I move one value from listbox A to listbox B and click save. The third list box can reflect the value that I save.

In my second attempt: after the first attempt, listbox B still contains the value from listbox A, so this time, I move that value back to listbox A and click save. In the result, in the third list box, I see that value disappear.

At this moment, there is no value in listbox B and I add another two button and write similar code to pretend move values between the third list box and listbox B.

I test it, I select the value from the combo box, the third list box shows the proper values. But when I select a value from the third list box and click the button to move it to listbox A. I think that value will move to the listbox A but the result is nothing happens.

I try the other way, I select a value from listbox A and click the button to move it to the third button. Again the result is nothing happens.

After those fail attempts, I think the problem occurs in the buttons.

Here are the code of the two buttons

Button 1 (move value to the third listbox):

```
if (viewScope.ALstBoxItem) {
                        var sel = [].concat(viewScope.ALstBoxItem);
                        for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
                            viewScope.totalItems.add(sel[i]); 
                            viewScope.AselectItems.remove(sel[i]);
                        }
                        viewScope.totalItems.sort(); 
                        viewScope.ALstBoxItem = "";
                    }
```

Button 2 (move value to the listbox A):

```
if (viewScope.TotalItemsVariable) {
                        var sel = [].concat(viewScope.TotalItemsVariable);
                        for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
                            viewScope.AselectItems.add(sel[i]);                     
                            viewScope.totalInItem.remove(sel[i]); 
                        }        
                        viewScope.AselectItems.sort();                         
                        viewScope.TotalItemsVariable = "";
                    }
```

Recall to comments in the question, I guess I should focus on the values in the listbox, not the button. I search on the internet about hide selected value and find these websites almost can give me the idea to solve the problem:

[xpages hiding/showing fields based on a combobox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619967/xpages-hiding-showing-fields-based-on-a-combobox-value)

[Hiding based on previous combo box choice in xpages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528215/hiding-based-on-previous-combo-box-choice-in-xpages)

https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/dynamical_elements_on_xpages.htm

I try to apply those summary to suit my case but I still cannot move values after I save.

Grateful if someone can give advice please. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are talking about deleting *values* from a list box but you are trying to do this by deleting *documents*. You should not be looking at deleting documents.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten, thanks you comment. May I ask a question about documents and values please? I think I mixed them up in my original question.

Comment: For example, there is a raw data, called "abc", if I put it in the list box, should I say that "abc" is a list box value? Even I write some code in the listbox, that "abc" is still a list box value? If I saved "abc", so that raw data becomes a document?

Comment: I don't see any reference to a document data source  - only viewScope values.

Comment: I read this website [XPages - How to pass a Document Data Source to a Custom Control](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/09082009095808AMWEBJDV.htm). So in my case, do I need to create a custom control for document data source?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hello @Learner, I follow the solution and try to do something similar in the application.However, I have some problems in the application, so I would like to ask here and seek for advice. In the application, I can display overall values in one listbox(consider it is listbox A in your case) and I can also show the main value (combobox) that I am looking for and the relevant values in other listbox (listbox B). However, I cannot add options to the listbox whereas I can remove options in the listbox. I am using viewScope for the listbox, do you have any ideas why I cause the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please step back and think about what you are building. You have two list boxes. They contain values, not documents, so a deleteSelectedDocument simple action can't work. Similarly, access to delete documents isn't relevant.

Also, from previous questions of this topic, I don't think you are setting **values** in the listboxes, you are using the events to set **options**, i.e. the options are not highlighted and so selected in the listbox, they are just sitting in the listboxes as options available for selection. Look at the code you're using to add options to the listboxes and use the corresponding code to remove the options.

I've added an image that corresponds to what I think you're trying to build, and the difference between "value" and "option", except in your example it sounds like you're moving the option from ListBox 1 to ListBox 2 as soon as it's selected, not using an "Add" button. Or to break the process down further, it sounds like, when an option in ListBox 1 is selected, you are looking to remove it from the list of options in ListBox 1 and add it to the list of options in ListBox 2. On your save, it sounds like you're wanting to store the options into a NotesDocument and, when you return, set the options for your ListBoxes based on what is stored in the NotesDocument.

If so, the questions and answers on this topic have given you everything you need to code those steps in the process.

[image: ListBox example]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my previous questions, I receive useful answers to improve the application. I can move values between two listboxes and save them.

Comment: But when I retrieve those values, the listboxes can display the proper values that I saved before. I cannot move those values and get exception message.

Comment: If I don't save the combo box and two listboxes values, I can exchange values between two listboxes.

Comment: So I am thinking about add one more button and that button is used to delete the values that I saved.

Comment: Maybe I should edit the content of the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: If they are highlighted, think of them as "values". If they're not (and I suspect they are not, they just have a clear background and are "selectable"), then think of them as "options". That should help you code it to achieve what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I search on the internet with this keywords 'xpage hide selected value' I find some of the website mention about "rendered" this term. I have a quick search about rendered in xpages. I feel confuse if I put rendered in the listbox values.

Comment: If the selected values in the listbox are highlighted, I am not sure that I should rendered them?

Comment: Hopefully the screenshot and update in my answer clarifies. I don't think you're breaking down what you actually want to achieve into more granular processes and consequently misunderstanding the ListBox. As a result you've going off on incorrect tracks like deleting documents and hiding selected values, which are unnecessary and won't achieve what you're trying to get them to do. To be clear, I don't think it's an coding complexity here, more a need to break down the functional process into granular steps, to understand what your code needs to do.

Comment: Hello @PaulStephenWithers, I follow your solution and try to do something similar in the application. I can display overall values in one listbox(consider it is the listbox on the left side from the screenshot) and I can also show the main value (the editbox from the screenshot) and the relevant values in other listbox (the listbox on the right side). However, I cannot add options to the right side listbox whereas I can remove options in the right side listbox. I am using viewScope for the listbox, do you have any ideas why I cause the problem? Thank you